# Jersey and Jackson: Reponse POJO contains JsonObject

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I'm making a web app using Jersey and Jackson. I've made a response POJO of the following type:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class ResponsePojo {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String imageUrl;
    private JsonObject queryParams;

    public ResponsePojo(Integer id, String name, String imageUrl, JsonObject queryParams) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.queryParams = queryParams;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public JsonObject getQueryParams() {
        return queryParams;
    }

    public void setQueryParams(JsonObject queryParams) {
        this.queryParams = queryParams;
    }
}
```

I receive a proper JSON response from the webAPI when I omit the `private JsonObject queryParams;` field. How can I return a JSON from inside the response POJO?

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: my.package.Response["list"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->my.package.ResponsePojo["queryParams"]->com.google.gson.JsonObject["asJsonObject"])
```

Comment: What do you expect your JSON to look like?

Comment: Why are trying to mix Gson with Jackson? Which one are you actually using for serialization?

Comment: The JSON would be any normal JSON.
I'm using Jackson for serialisation. I'm open to any other alternatives. I basically want to attach a JSON to the field queryParams.

Comment: BTW, I've achieved it via Map. Looking for any other better alternatives.